# How to disable AWS Route53 Resolver Network Interface?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I registered a domain on AWS. And I find it costs $0.125 per hours because of I using the  Route53 Resolver Network Interface.
How Can I disable the Route53 Resolver Network Interface? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't find such an option in the AWS Console, you can use AWS CLI's [delete-resolver-endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53resolver/delete-resolver-endpoint.html).